# Extracting multiple data from column with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I've a file with information like this

```
Info A: 1
Info B: 2
Info C: 3
Info D: 4

Info A: 1
Info B: 2
Info C: 123
Info D: 4
```

Now I'm trying to get the line with Info C but I need it separately. I need a command to get the output of Info C of the first block and a command to get the Info C from the second block.
This command works for me, to get the Info C of both blocks. In the first part of the command, I'm deleting all the stuff except the lines with Info C.  In the second part of the command, I'm deleting the string "Info C: "

```
cat test2 | sed -e '/Info C: /!d' -e 's/Info C: //'
```

The output contains only the value:

```
3
123
```

Now, to get it separately, I've tried several arguments for sed but nothing works for me.

The following solution works fine for me. I just print the first or the last line

```
cat test2 | sed -e '/Info C: /!d' -e 's/Info C: //' | sed -n '$p'
cat test2 | sed -e '/Info C: /!d' -e 's/Info C: //' | sed -n '1p'
```

But I wonder, if there is a solution without a second pipeline for sed?

Comment: Are there always two blocks in your input and is it guaranteed that each block contains a line matching `Info C` ? Keep in mind you can always save the result into an array and use `${array[0]}` and `${array[1]}` later instead of saving into separate variables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your shell supports arrays, you can do:

```
$ infoC=( $(sed -n 's/Info C: \(.*\)/\1/p' file ) )
$ echo ${infoC[0]}
3
$ echo ${infoC[1]}
123
```

Or, with GNU `sed`:

```
infoC=($(sed -rn 's/Info C: (.*)/\1/p' file ))
```

I'm using a simpler `sed` command here. The `-n` suppresses normal output, so it only prints the lines you tell it to. The substitution operator matches the lines with `Info C:` and *captures* (with the parentheses) the value which is saved as `\1`. So it will replace the line with `\1` and print it (the `p` at the end).

The `var=( $(command) )` is a way of saving the output of `command` in the array `var`. The first element is then `${var[0]}`, the second `${var[1]}` etc. Here, the array name is `infoC`.

Comment: `/Info C: /s///p`

Comment: If you'd like it at full `sed -n '/Info C: /s///p' file`

Comment: @Costas yeah, my bad, I deleted my previous comment. Could you also explain *why* that works? It looks like its replacing nothing with nothing. It would be great if you could post an answer showing this and explaining how it works. It looks like the substitution operator deletes anything matched by the match operator.

Comment: @Costas - you don't need `-n` + `p` just `sed '/Info C: /!d;s///'`

Comment: `sed -rn 's/Info C: (.*)/\1/p'` can be simplified to `sed -n 's/Info C: //p'`

Comment: alternate if grep and pcre are available: `grep -oP 'Info C: \K.*'`

Comment: for `sed -n '/Info C: /s///p'` from the manual, ``The empty regular expression `//' repeats the last regular expression match (the same holds if the empty regular expression is passed to the `s' command)``

Answer (score 0):

```
cat test2 | sed -e '/Info C: /!d' -e 's/Info C: //' | sed -n '1p;$p'
```